# Spring OAuth2 - How to use grant type `password` and `client_credentials` together but with different expired time

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, access-token

I am using Spring Security OAuth2 to implement authentication between my web application and the central authorization server. I use grant type `password` and `client_credentials` together. The web application use `client_credentials` token when the user has not logged in, and use `password` token when the user has already logged in.

For the `password` token, I set the expiration time to be short and provide a long-live refresh token for renewing the access token. The expiration time configuration is done by changing the value of column `access_token_validity` in table `oauth_client_details`.

```
| client_id |           authorized_grant_types          | access_token_validity |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 my_web_app   password,refresh_token,client_credentials           900
```

But for the `client_credentials` token, I want to make that it never expires. But Spring use the value in `access_token_validity` for both type of token.

How can I set the `access_token_validity` separatedly for the 2 token types?

Comment: A work-around would be to use two different clients.

Answer (score 0):

Investigating the code, I come up with the following solution.

First, add `{ "client_token_validity": 2000000000 }` to column `additional_information` in table `oauth_client_details`

```
|    client_id    |              authorized_grant_types                  |     access_token_validity     |       additional_information
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 my_web_app            password,refresh_token,client_credentials                   900                         { "client_token_validity": 2000000000 }
```

Then, extend the `DefaultTokenServices`, overriding the method `getAccessTokenValiditySeconds` to read the above additional information.

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
public ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService() {
    return new JdbcClientDetailsService(dataSource);
}

@Bean
@Primary
public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
    MyJwtTokenService myJwtTokenService = new MyJwtTokenService(tokenBlackListService);
    tokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService());
    return myJwtTokenService;
}

public class MyJwtTokenService extends DefaultTokenServices {
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void setClientDetailsService(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
        this.clientDetailsService = clientDetailsService;
        super.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected int getAccessTokenValiditySeconds(OAuth2Request clientAuth) {
        String grantType = clientAuth.getGrantType();
        if ("client_credentials".equals(grantType)) {
            ClientDetails client = this.clientDetailsService.loadClientByClientId(clientAuth.getClientId());
            Object clientTokenValidity = client.getAdditionalInformation().get("client_token_validity");
            if (clientTokenValidity != null) {
                return (int) clientTokenValidity;
            }
        }

        return super.getAccessTokenValiditySeconds(clientAuth);
    }
}
```